# Simulating and adding total at end

Tags: python, while-loop, global, simulation

Here's my code:

```
import random, time
def example():
    var = random.randint(1,100)
    if var <= 99:
        var = 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'
    if var == 100 :
        var = 'b', 'c', 'd'
    noACount = 0
    someVariable = 0
    if 'a' in var:
        someVariable = someVariable + 1
    if 'a' in var:
        someVariable = someVariable + 12
    else:
        print('Item a not present')
        noACount = noACount + 1
        time.sleep(1)
    print('The amount of someVariable you have is ' + str(someVariable) + '.')
    print('The amount of times A was not present was' + str(noACount) + '.')
```

So far I have finished this, but I 'm trying to make it like a simulation. I'm trying to get it to ask you how many times you want to execute this script and at the end tell you the amount of someVariable was in total and nACount in total. For example if my variable someVariable was poptarts, and noACount was apples, at the end of doing it x times, it would tell you that the amount of poptarts you bought was x, and the amount of times you bought apples was x. I tried to do this with a while loop, but that didn't work at all, so know I'm stuck trying to figure it out.

Comment: "I tried to do this with a while loop, but that didn't work at all" - what do you mean? any code you used, errors, unexpected output?

Comment: I put it in a while loop but I couldn't figure out a way to add the values I get from each one into a total instead of them keep overwriting eachother. Ex: someVariable = 13, but when it loops again I couldn't figure out how to make it add up instead of keep overwriting someVariable to the same value of 13

Comment: I did while True: (Code here)

Answer (score 0):

You need to define someVariable before you enter the loop. Then it is in the function scope and not only in the loop scope.

Example 1:

```
while True:
    someVariable = 0 #The variable is initiated to 0 => bad
    someVariable +=1
print someVariable #outputs 1
```

Example 2:

```
someVariable = 0
while True:
    ...doSomeMagic...
    someVariable +=1
print someVariable #someVariable now holds whatever we counted up to
```

Please note that "while True" initiates an infinite loop, which must be broken by calling "break" when your condition is satisfied.